# Can't upgrade JupyterLab to latest version

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I am trying to upgrade JupyterLab to pre-release but when I check the installed version after upgrading I still get the old version (0.33.11).

To install the pre-release I used:

`pip install -U --pre jupyterlab`

I have also tried to upgrade to the latest version (0.35.6) using Anaconda:

`conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab`

I also tried with this:

`conda update jupyterlab`

But again in all cases after installation I still get version 0.33.11.

When I run conda again I see that conda donwloads version 0.33.11. This is the message I get from it:

The following packages will be downloaded:

```
package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
conda-4.6.14               |           py27_0         2.1 MB
jupyterlab-0.33.11         |           py27_0        10.0 MB
------------------------------------------------------------
                                       Total:        12.0 MB
```

Comment: How do you check the installed version? When you upgrade with pip, conda might not know about it. What was the output of the pip install attempt, did it download something or not?

Comment: I use `jupyter lab --version`.

Pip does not download anything. The output is a whole set of lines starting with
 
`"Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade:"`

Comment: I strongly suggest using conda in general.

Answer (score 3):

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab=1.0.2
```

Solve the problem for me.